# Get amounts of div's? - XPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

I want to get all images sources with PHP. So I want to use something like that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('//myXpath');
```

But I have two questions. I have multiple div's who are matching my div. Of course, this div `//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div` is unique. But how can I iterate through all divs?

They are continuing like this: `//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div` & `//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div` & `//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div`.

And my second question is how what I'am supposed to commit to the `loadHTML()` function? -> `$dom->loadHTML($file);`

I want to search in the actual HTML site a user has loaded!

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Why do you want `XPath` for `div` if you need to get images sources? Also note that only one answer could be marked as "Accepted", so you'd better submit separate tickets for each question you want to ask...

Comment: Because I must use PHP to get something from my database!

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. However, if you want you can "alert" the number of divs in a document using jQuery like that: alert($(document).find('div').length); If you want to interact with php, you should use AJAX. I cannot be more specific since you haven't provided any sample of code.

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with JavaScript, jQuery, HTML or CSS.